# My App does not restart 'Bluemix'

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

I want to restart my app in Bluemix, but I am receiving this message:

```
BXNUI2055E: Unable to connect to Cloud Foundry because of the
following exception: "Read timed out." If the problem persists, see
the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to check
service status, review troubleshooting information, or for information
about getting help.
```

I do not understand what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an intermittent platform issue. Were there any issues listed on the [status page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) during the time you were trying this?

If you redo the same command, it should work again.

Comment: According to the status page noted above, the US-South region is experiencing intermittent issues...